# Sql Server Aggregation or Pivot Table Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to write a query that will tell me the number of customers who had a certain number of transactions each week. I don't know where to start with the query, but I'd assume it involves an aggregate or pivot function. I'm working in SqlServer management studio.

Currently the data is looks like where the first column is the customer id and each subsequent column is a week :

```
|Customer| 1 | 2| 3 |4 |
----------------------
|001     |1 | 0| 2 |2 |
|002     |0 | 2| 1 |0 |
|003     |0 | 4| 1 |1 |
|004     |1 | 0| 0 |1 |
```

I'd like to see a return like the following:

```
|Visits |1 | 2| 3 |4 |
----------------------
|0      |2 | 2| 1 |0 |
|1      |2 | 0| 2 |2 |
|2      |0 | 1| 1 |1 |
|4      |0 | 1| 0 |0 |
```

What I want is to get the count of customer transactions per week. E.g. during the 1st week 2 customers (i.e. `002` and `003`) had 0 transactions, 2 customers (i.e. `001` and `004`) had 1 transaction, whereas zero customers had more than 1 transaction

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the count of customer transactions per week. E.g. during the 1st week 2 customers (i.e. `002` and `003`) had 0 transactions, 2 customers (i.e. `001` and `004`) had 1 transaction, whereas zero customers had more than 1 transaction.

Comment: ok. I've made those changes. Hope it is reopened

Comment: It looks like the sample output for week for is missing a value 1 for for 0 visits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below will get you the result you want, but note that it has the column names hard coded. It's easy to add more week columns, but if the number of columns is unknown then you might want to look into a solution using dynamic SQL (which would require accessing the information schema to get the column names). It's not that hard to turn it into a fully dynamic version though.

```
select 
    Visits
    , coalesce([1],0) as Week1 
    , coalesce([2],0) as Week2 
    , coalesce([3],0) as Week3 
    , coalesce([4],0) as Week4
from (
    select *, count(*) c from (
    select '1' W, week1 Visits from t union all
    select '2' W, week2 Visits from t union all
    select '3' W, week3 Visits from t union all
    select '4' W, week4 Visits from t ) a
group by W, Visits
) x pivot ( max (c) for W in ([1], [2], [3], [4]) ) as pvt;
```

In the query your table is called `t` and the output is:

```
Visits  Week1   Week2   Week3   Week4
0       2       2       1       1
1       2       0       2       2
2       0       1       1       1
4       0       1       0       0
```